# using WPPB shortcodes without the plugin

Tags: plugins, shortcode

recently I got a Wordpress website maintenance and the owner told me to remove email verification from the sign-up process so I went to the sign-up page and saw this shortcode

```
[wppb-register form_name]
```

and then searched and found out that this shortcode is for WordPress profile builder but this site doesn't have this plugin
is that possible that we use shortcode from a plugin that is not installed?

Comment: It would be possible to recreate the shortcode and name it whatever you want but that seems unlikely.  Are you sure this shortcode is controlling the form?  If you remove it does the form go away?  If so you should be able to search the site files for "wppb-register"

Comment: thank you for your response I check and found out that shortcode is not handling the sign-up or sign-in, again thank you